# Xfce: some notifications not disappearing

Tags: xfce, notification, notification-area, xubuntu, jupiter

Some of my notifications on XFCE are not disapearing (especially those from jupiter) automatically. Timeout is set to 5 seconds and I can manually close them. What's happening?

I'm using Xubuntu 12.10, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is related to `notify-send`, it ignores the timeout parameter: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/390508

Jupiter uses `notify-send` to create the desktop notifications. As a workaround the Jupiter's notify script can be edited and all `-t` parameters removed:

`sudo sed -i 's/-t [0-9]\+//g' /usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/notify`

The notifications will be shown for a few seconds then they'll vanish.

Answer (score -1):

You could probably blast them away with xkill. But that's more a workaround, not a real solution, sorry.

Comment: A comment may be better.

Comment: A description (and sample code) of how to use `xkill` in this exact situation would be helpful. Which process do you kill for it to go away?

Comment: (The process is `xfce4-notifyid` by the way, if you want to edit that into your answer)