# How to clear jupiter's notification?

Tags: 12.04, display, resolution, notification, jupiter

I used an external display some time before. After that there is a notification of 'New Resolution' everytime the startup of my xfce.

Look like this:

[image]

This is really annoying, so I want to know how to clear the notification?

I have reinstalled the Jupiter, it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Hope this [link][^2] should help you. :)
 [^2]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/207739/xfce-some-notifications-not-disappearing

Comment: @midnight Thanks. The posts are helpful for me!